# Joomla module styling -> Echo <div> structure?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

I'm trying to think of a really nice way to echo the module styling for Joomla. I have:

```
 <div class="module">
    <div class="module_inner">
       <h1>Some other title, eh?</h1>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
       sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>  
 </div>
 <div class="module_bot"></div>
```

I want to output all modules with this sctructure, when a user creates a new module (HTML). The below, might get messy having multiple OR's. Messy?

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('module1')): ?>

 // echo div structure
 // echo module contents

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any way I can do this more Object Orientated, so I don't have alot of code on my template index.php. Possibly functions?

Just to be clear, My question is: How do I output a div structure, styling a module, with php so the user doesnt have to input the div structure in the Custom HTML module, it does it all for them -> They just type Header + Text + image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own module types within your template. Looks for modules.php. You can add a new type and then use it in your main index.php template